# gdal_translate using /vsistdin/ and /vsistdout/ to pipe commands

Tags: gdal-translate

I am trying to pipe some of my commands with gdal_translate's output. These commands should read from standard input, so I'm writing to /vsistdout/. However, I am getting some errors. To be a bit more generic, I tried some other commands to illustrate the issues I face:

```
$ gdal_translate -of JPEG2000 Lenna.png /vsistdout/ | gdal_translate -of PNG /vsistdin/ Lenna01.png
ERROR 6: Read or update mode not supported on /vsistdout
ERROR 3: Unable to create file /vsistdout/.

ERROR 4: `/vsistdin/' not recognised as a supported file format.

GDALOpen failed - 4
`/vsistdin/' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

However, the following works:

```
$ gdal_translate -of JPEG Lenna.png /vsistdout/ | gdal_translate -of PNG /vsistdin/ Lenna0.png
Input file size is 512, 512
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

(In my tests, I am using my image format, which gets the same error as JPEG2000).
Is it that gdal_translate has a per-format support of the /vsistdout/ (and /vsistdin/) parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comparing the GeoTIFF format page:

> Streaming operations
>
> Starting with GDAL 2.0, the GeoTIFF driver can support reading or
>   writing TIFF files (with some restrictions detailed below) in a
>   streaming compatible way. When reading a file from /vsistdin/, a named
>   pipe (on Unix), or if forcing streamed reading by setting the
>   TIFF_READ_STREAMING configuration option to YES, the GeoTIFF driver
>   will assume that the TIFF Image File Directory (IFD) is at the
>   beginning of the file, i.e. at offset 8 for a classical TIFF file or
>   at offset 16 for a BigTIFF file. The values of the tags of array type
>   must be contained at the beginning of file, after the end of the IFD
>   and before the first image strip/tile. The reader must read the
>   strips/tiles in the order they are written in the file. For a pixel
>   interleaved file (PlanarConfiguration=Contig), the recommended order
>   for a writer, and thus for a reader, is from top to bottom for a
>   strip-organized file or from top to bottom, which a chunk of a block
>   height, and left to right for a tile-organized file. For a band
>   organized file (PlanarConfiguration=Separate), the above order is
>   recommended with the content of the first band, then the content of
>   the second band, etc... Technically this order corresponds to
>   increasing offsets in the TileOffsets/StripOffsets tag. This is the
>   order that the GDAL raster copy routine will assume.
>
> [...]
>
> When writing a file to /vsistdout/, a named pipe (on Unix), or when
>   definiting the STREAMABLE_OUTPUT=YES creation option, the CreateCopy()
>   method of the GeoTIFF driver will generate a file with the above
>   defined constraints (related to position of IFD and block order), and
>   this is only supported for a uncompressed file. The Create() method
>   also supports creating streamable compatible files, but the writer
>   must be careful to set the projection, geotransform or metadata before
>   writing image blocks (so that the IFD is written at the beginning of
>   the file). And when writing image blocks, the order of blocks must be
>   the one of the above paragraph, otherwise errors will be reported.

and the JPeg2000 page:

> The driver uses the VSI Virtual File API, so it can read JPEG2000 compressed NITF files.

it seems that this is still being implemented on a format by format basis and that JP2K only supports read not write.

Comment: So, basically, it's down to a format-by-format basis, and if I want it for my format, I'll have to implement it.